# How can I confirm whether there is a leak in my shower threshold?

Tags: shower, leak, grout

I had my shower remodeled about 3 years ago and recently have started to notice some issues in the grout around the threshold. There appears to be some mineral deposits at the base of the threshold on the shower side as well as the other.

There are some other discolorations and cracks in the grout which are only around the threshold. If this was normal wear I would expect to see it everywhere in the shower, not just around the threshold.

Is this a sign of a bigger issue like water getting into the threshold or is this normal?

**Exterior pics:**
[image]

[image]

**Interior pics:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The picture with the drain is most likely inside the shower. It would be helpful to know if the other pictures are inside or outside, as they're all close enough to make it very difficult to tell. It's good that they're close, they provide a good view, it would be very helpful to [edit] your post to indicate "Inside" then group all the inside pics and "Outside" and group all the outside pics. Or, if they're all interior, let us know that.

Comment: Photos   #4 and #5 ( and maybe #3) show that some caulking has separated and should be removed and replaced. One can assume that if these photos are of the inside of the shower pan and  the caulk is not closing the gap, as it is intended to do, then water could pass into the gaps.

Comment: @FreeMan First 2 are outside the shower, the tiles are square.  Inside the shower has hexagons.

Comment: pic 4 looks like the floor and wall pulled away slightly and has a nice long crack between the tile and the grout.  Whether that leaks out or not depends on how the underlayment is installed.  I'd definitely fix that part.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to confirm if your shower basin has leaks around the tile is to plug the drain. Remove the grate and install a stopper of the appropriate diameter. It must be 100% plugged. Next fill the basin with water. It is easier to use 5 gallon buckets filled from another water source. Fill the basin to just below the curb. Mark the water height with tape and/or marker.

Wait awhile and check if the water level has dropped. If it hasn't let it stay over night and recheck. If no noticeable change in water level there are no leaks in the grout or joints.

I would suggest re-grouting those joints that have missing grout and any others that have loose grout.